# How to superimpose an image on table?

Tags: tables, graphics

I wish to superimpose a colored call-out object as an image indicating a particular cell in a table.The call-out box will be pointed to a cell and will lie over few other cells.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
\midrule
11 & 12 & \tikz[overlay, remember picture,anchor=base] \node (Center){13}; \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
31 & \tikz[overlay, remember picture,anchor=base] \node (Mark){32}; & 33 \\
41 & 42 & 43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, note/.style={rectangle callout, fill=#1}]
\node [note=red!50, callout absolute pointer={(Mark)}] at (Center) {This is the cell!};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To cover more than one row with call-out node, you can fix a `minimum height` in `note/.style`.

```
note/.style={rectangle callout, fill=#1, minimum height=1cm}
```

[image]

And if you prefer some other placement, just change call-out `anchor` and centering position, i.e.,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, 
     note/.style={rectangle callout, fill=#1, 
     minimum height=1cm, anchor=north}]
\node [note=red!50, callout absolute pointer={(Mark)}] at (Center.north) 
      {This is the cell!};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ignasi. This is what I wanted.If the call-out box 2 rows of 3rd column, how should it be written?

Comment: @ShalabhJain Please, look at updated answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: @ShalabhJain. Glad to help you. Would you mind to [`accept`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it?